# getting sound from external speaker with an audio interface

Tags: guitar

I'm trying to get sound from my audio interface by using an external speaker. My current chain is like this.  guitar -> mooer ge200 multi fx -> behringer umc204hd -> speaker. I connect the speaker to audio interface with a rca male to 3.5mm cable. I can hear the sound of pc from the speaker (youtube etc..) but I can hear the guitar only from the headphone output of the audio interface. Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you activated the direct monitoring (DM)? Otherwise you need to make a connection between the inputs and the outputs, for instance in a daw.